# Hibernate criteria like not found

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-mapping

hi people i need to implement a criteria search on hibernate that compare to string and return true only if string match exactly with another string, for example:

```
String x = "aa"; --> field of Class
String y = "Aa"; --> passed as argument method

Criteria crit = getSession()
.createCriteria(Class.class)
.add(Restrictions.like("x", "y")) --> same value for both string, but really its not the same, aa its not equals Aa.
```

im treat to use:

1. equals with the same result
2. matchmode and not work

this should be case sensitive.

Thanks

Comment: is your database configured to be case sensitive?

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet,

```
Criteria crit = getSession() .createCriteria(Class.class) 
                             .add(Restrictions.ilike(x,y))...
```

Answer (score 0):

1. is it your aim to write `x` and `y` in doublequotes in the like function?
2. why don't you use the equals function?

   criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(propertyName, value));

Have a look at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#eq%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29

Comment: .add(Restrictions.eq("name", name)) is same -- return true, although "name" is "aa" and name (without "") is "Aa"